# SonarQube is not analysing all the bugs

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube for analysing my windows form .NET project but from the past few days for my certain projects SonarQube is behaving strangely it is not capturing all the errors but the line of code count is correct. On one form it is treating a certain code as a bug and on another page it is showing it as a bug. To confirm this I have created a bug explicitly but SonarQube is not showing that peice of code as error but SonarLint is working fine it is showing that as an error.

I am using VS2015 so in my errorlist all the sonar errors are listed as warnings but these errors are not on my dashboard there are only very few errors are listed on my dashboard previously it was working fine and I have also not made any changes.

Configuration details are as follow:
SonarQube - 5.3
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner - 2.0
C# plugin - 4.5
.NET framework - 4.6
Windows Forms application

Please help and let me know if you require any more details.

Thanks & Regards,
Nikhil Gupta

Answer (score 0):

I too face these kind of issues.

Solution:

This is because of having single file for both .cs file and .designer.cs file (which is auto generated code), so sonar excluding this auto generated files.

If you split this file to 2 separate files as .cs file and .designer file, it will not excluded by sonar and it will analyse all winform files as well.